# Not able to publish azure service to remote cluster

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-service-fabric

When i Am clicking Publish

[image]

It is showing Following Powershell Error:

[image]

Comment: What is your ApplicationType name?

Comment: @Wouter WrkLdmon(An)

Comment: Is the ApplicationType already registered in the cluster? If so, try unprovisioning it first.

Comment: @Wouter In which cluster Local or Remote?

Comment: The cluster you are trying to publish to. In this case your remote cluster.

Comment: @Wouter No it is not registered to Remote cluster.

Comment: Can you provide some detail of the name of the application manifest file?

Comment: @duongthaiha ApplicationTypeName="WLMananyApplicationType"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Found the solution
Created a new azure cluster and deployed to it and it worked!