# How to deploy Azure service fabric project on to a remote cluster(Azure)

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have Created a cluster in Azure http://******.######.cloudapp.azure.com:19080
but don't know how to deploy my service fabric project on to it.
Link to application manifest
[ApplicationManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HYXp.png)

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty well documented, unless you are getting specific errors, which you then will need to reference to get some worthwhile help

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-publish-app-remote-cluster

Comment: Here is the error details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384647/not-able-to-publish-azure-service-to-remote-cluster

Comment: Can you upload or send a link to (stored somewhere else) the application manifest? you would get to it by if you're in visual studio online going to the build, then artifacts, then downloading the drop folder, and finding it in the deployment package folder. In visual studio locally, you'd go to the project folder then the ApplicationPackageRoot to get it

Comment: Ok I see the issue maybe. I think your application type name (in the applicationmanifest element) is either too long, or the _ character isn't valid for it. In looking at any of mine, and any of the microsoft examples, there aren't any _ characters in the names.

Comment: can i directly change application type name in the application manifest file

Comment: you would do it inside your project in the applicationmanifest file and retry the deploy, but yes. It would be in the applicationpackageroot folder.

Comment: I changed the application type name in applicationmanifest file but still it is showing the same error

Comment: I tried Deploying few other simple projects they are also showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is to use the [powershell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications). You can also right-click your application in visual studio and select "Publish". Make sure you are using the correct publish profile.

Answer (score 0):

Within Visual Studio, navigate to your Publish Profiles folder under the application and copy/paste the existing cloud.xml file and then rename appropriately. Ensure that you use the correct public facing I.P for your cluster, which will most likely be the load balancer.

The line should look like the following.

```
<ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="<YOUR IP>:19000" />
```

Example:

```
<ClusterConnectionParameters ConnectionEndpoint="151.41.35.35:19000" />
```

However, if the cluster is secured you may need additional information. These options are shown within the commented Cluster Connection Parameters of the cloud.xml file.

Right click on the application, select publish and ensure the new publish profile is selected. Visual studio will attempt to validate the connection. Try to publish and keep an eye on the output window for insight in to the process.

Comment: (My cluster is not secured ) when i click on publish it is showing PowerShell Script ERROR

Comment: If it is unsecure, you should be able to amend the publish profile to include the line mentioned in my answer. If the PS script is causing an error, could you please edit your question and include the error?

Comment: Here is the error details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44384647/not-able-to-publish-azure-service-to-remote-cluster